Wrong Bazel Execution Platform Selection After Upgrading to Bazel 7
I am trying to upgrade from bazel 6.5.0 to 7.1.1 and i am encountering problems relating to execution platforms selection.
I have 3 different execution platforms which each one of them has a different constraint_value in the same constraint_setting.
In order to select the compatible execution platform to my target i am using the exec_compatible_with attribute to specify constraint_value that only one of  them has.
Everything worked fine using bazel 6.5.0, and the target was executed on the desired platform, i have inspected it using bazel test -s //target and saw that the
action Testing was executed on the right platform:
SUBCOMMAND: # //target [action 'Testing //target, configuration: ....., execution platform: //path/to/platform/target].
When upgrading to bazel 7.1.1, I have saw that only the action Compiling is selecting the desired execution platform but all others  (Linking, Testing) are using different and wrong execution platform that does not have the constraint_value (which appear to be the first one in the extra execution platforms that i am registering using the --extra_execution_platforms in the .bazelrc) and causing my test to fail.
Does someone know or can help me find what have changed between bazel 6.5.0 to bazel 7.1.1 or 7.0.2 regarding the selection of execution platforms to different actions (specifically Testing)?
Thanks all in advance!

Probably best to file an issue with a repro case on bazelbuild/bazel
